# Looping through MySQL select data with PHP if statements

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to return results from a database and output to HTML.
If feature=1 then I want the image associated to the product to display. Underneath this, I then also want the title of all results to display regardless of the value of feature. This is also all grouped by release_date in the variable `$group_date`.

The code I've supplied at the bottom allows me to retrieve data like this (I think this is down to it looping through one row and outputting before going on to the next, but i'm not sure what the solution is):

```
   group_date
         -----        -----        -----
         |img|        |img|        |img|
   title -----  title -----  title ----- title 

   group_date 2
         -----        -----        -----
         |img|        |img|        |img|
   title -----  title -----  title ----- title title
```

I would like the results to be displayed like this

```
   group_date
   -----  -----  -----
   |img|  |img|  |img|
   -----  -----  -----
   title 1
   title 2
   title 3
   title 4

   group_date 2
   -----  -----  -----
   |img|  |img|  |img|
   -----  -----  -----
   title 1
   title 2
   title 3
   title 4
   title 5
   ....
```

Here is the code I currently have

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_GROUP
);
$db = new PDO($dsn,"user", "pass", $opt);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY release_date ASC, rating DESC");
$group_date = "";
?>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
    <div>
<div id="contentWrapper">
<?php
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
$group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
?>
<?=$group_date;?>
<div>
<?php }
$feature= $row['feature'];

if($feature=='1')
{?>
<a href="<?=$row['product_url']?>" title="<?=$row['title']?>">
    <img src="<?=$row['img_url']?>" width='180' height='267' alt="<?=$row['title']?>"/>
</a>
<?php } ?>

<?=$row['title']?> <br>

<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>

</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made few changes in the code - please try and let me know. I have basically saved the titles in a string and printed them only when the date is being printed and then re initialized it to "". I have put //ADDED in front of the lines which I have put in your code.

```
<?php
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_GROUP
);
$db = new PDO($dsn,"user", "pass", $opt);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY release_date ASC, rating DESC");
$group_date = "";
$title = ""; //ADDED
?>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div>
<div>
<div id="contentWrapper">
<?php
     while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     if ($group_date !== substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10)) {
     $group_date = substr($row["release_date"], 0, 10);
 ?>
<?php
    echo $title == "" ? "" : $title; //ADDED
    $title = ""; //ADDED
    echo $group_date;
?>
<div>
<?php }
$feature= $row['feature'];

if($feature=='1')
{?>
<a href="<?=$row['product_url']?>" title="<?=$row['title']?>">
    <img src="<?=$row['img_url']?>" width='180' height='267' alt="<?=$row['title']?>"/>
</a>
<?php } ?>

<?php
 $title = $title . "<br>" . $row['title']; //ADDED
 ?> <br>

 <?php } ?>
 </div>
 </div>

 </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: After trying your code, it seems to be almost what I want. I'm getting two issues: it adds a line break for all results where there isn't an image. And the titles seem to be missing after the images on the last set of grouped results.

Comment: I've fixed the line break issue between images by removing the `<br>` from `<?php
 $title = $title . "<br>" . $row['title']; //ADDED
 ?> <br>`. I think the last results are missing because the titles are linked to the next group date, but when it gets to the end there isn't another group date so the titles aren't printing. Do you know how to get round this?

Comment: Just put this line right after the while loop is getting closed - echo $title; This would print whatever is left in the title string at the end. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your many opening and closing php-tags make the code horrbile to read and understand.
My advice would be:

loop through all results and append your html markup to seperate strings:

```
while($row=...){
    $imgList2 .= "<Any html tags and content with any $row["variables"] inside>";
    $titleList2 .= "<Any html tags and content with any $row["variables"] inside>";
    if(condition for first list){
        $imgList1 .= "<Any html tags and content with any $row["variables"] inside>";
        $titleList1 .= "<Any html tags and content with any $row["variables"] inside>";
    }
}
//now echo both strings as you want
echo $fimgList1;
echo $titleList1;
echo $fimgList2;
echo $titleList2;
```

Another possibility would be to fill to seperate Arrays while looping through the results (one for each list) and looping through those arrays with foreach afterwards to display them.